# IF ELSE CONDITION

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working on the visual studio c++  and using these lines in my program.
Whenever i typed Get status , output is not "Good". the output will always be "invalid command" independent of Cstring strText . first two conditions are not working .

Kindly help . It should be worked according to the input strText.

```
         if ( strText == _T("Get status") )
     { 
                     MessageBox(_T("Good")); 


     }
         else if ( strText == _T("change") )
     {
         MessageBox(_T("Bad")); 
     }
     else 
         {
             MessageBox(_T("Invalid Command")); 
         }
```

Comment: and what type is returned by _T ?

Comment: @Alex, It should widen the string or not depending on a macro.

Comment: Are you sure you're typing `Get status`, not `get status` or `Get Status` or `Get status  `?

Comment: I guess `CString` doesn't overload `==` to do what you want, so the pointer values are compared. You should use the analogue of `strcmp` for `CString`.

Comment: i use _T() for CString. this will allow to build either ANSI and UNICODE verstion without changing the code. 

nothing to worry about _T

Comment: @Daniel,  [`CString` does overload `==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315046.aspx).

Comment: In `Cstring` the `operator==` comparison is case sensitive. Use e.g. [`CompareNoCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z695974k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to compare without case sensitivity.

Comment: @Nabeel - We still worry a bit about _T, because you don't ever want to build in ANSI mode, unless you are still using Windows 98.

Comment: Visual studio 2010 can't be run on Win 98 lol. i am using _T for just the safe side. I debug the program step by step to check the data , and suppose if i typed Get status, then strText has the "Get status" data , but if condition doesnt work. .. thats the problem

Comment: @Nabeel: `_T` doesn't add safety, but it certainly adds headaches. Use just `L""` and you're a lot safer.

Comment: Please post the code where strText is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CString::operator==` performs an exact case-sensitive match. If there's a mismatch in case or whitespace, then the strings will compare differently. I can't tell what's the problem in your case. Perhaps you could add `L"[" + strText + L"]"` to your messagebox, to see if there's some whitespace you overlooked.

In fact, even though CString claims to support Unicode, it doesn't. Two Unicode strigns that are formally identical, but differ in normalization are considered distinct. `L"ë"` may not be equal to `L"ë"`, according to `CString` if one is normalized and the other isn't. Windows has the `CompareStringEx` API, which is the swiss-army-knife of string comparisions and can deal with such details.